# Typedef an unconstrained float array in C

Tags: c, arrays, typedef

I made a typedef for float arrays, like this:

```
typedef float fooType[];
```

So that I can declare and initialise float arrays statically like this:

```
fooType myArray = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
```

That works fine. I can say `myArray[2]` with no problems and generally use my `fooType` as I'd like. In the context of my program it's very clear that `fooType` is an array type (it's actually a giant lookup table) which is why I'm not simply doing `typedef float fooType`.

How do I then declare and use a variable to point to `bar` and access the elements of `bar`? I cannot declare a simple variable like this:

```
fooType bar = myArray;
```

Since that errors with `invalid initializer`; I didn't expect it to work since the compiler doesn't know how much memory to allocate. I tried a few things with pointers:

```
fooType *bar = myArray;
```

This gives a warning: `initialization from incompatible pointer type` and errors when I access the elements with `bar[1]`.. This declares fine, as I'd expect it to since the types match now:

```
fooType *bar = &myArray;
```

But as above the compiler errors with an `invalid use of array with unspecified bounds` when I say `bar[1]`.

This works:

```
float *bar = myArray; 
float val = bar[3];
```

But I don't want to because I lose the readability of my typedef.

I've been buried for a long time in a cuddly OO world (Java), so I hope to understand from this what's idiomatic in C in this situation. I'm quite prepared to change my use of the typedef to suit convention if there is no direct solution. I have a feeling there is though, and it's not complicated.

Thanks

Comment: The bottom line is that you do **not** want to make typedefs for arrays... You can, but then you face all those "troubles". For example this thing `fooType myArray = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}; fooType bar = myArray;` means `float myArray[] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}; float bar[] = myArray;` Is it readable? :) Another "puzzle" is when you define a function prototype which takes `fooType` as _output_ argument. (Similar to `memset`, etc.)

Comment: That much is now clear @debleek63. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you're encountering here is the fact that arrays are not pointers in C, but rather decay to pointers to the first element when used on the right-hand side of the assignment operator.  Thus, if you declare an array like

```
fooType myArray = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
```

the type of `myArray` is `float[3]`, and &myArray is `(*float)[3]`, or "pointer to an array of 3 floats".  Thus you can't simply say

```
fooType *bar = myArray;
```

The type `fooType*` is not a pointer to a float ... thus it's an incompatible pointer type.  Doing

```
fooType* bar = &myArray;
```

does work, but the problem you're encountering is that `bar[1]` is not an element in the array `myArray`, since `bar` itself is a pointer.  You would have to dereference `bar` like `(*bar)[1]` to access an element in `myArray`. For instance:

```
typedef float fooType[];
fooType myArray = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
fooType* bar = &myArray;
(*bar)[1] = 5.0;
```

Finally, keep in mind that with C, you cannot assign one array to another array ... so you can'd do something like:

```
fooType bar = myArray;
```

This goes back to the whole issue of arrays and their decay into pointers to the first element, and the fact that the type of the array itself is not the same as the type of the first element in the array.

You may in the end simply want to typedef the array, and then typedef the array element types since of using `float` so that anyone using your code will know what one type of element belongs with the other.

Comment: Thanks Jason. That's a bit clearer now. I can't use the typedef then, it would seem, since its type is... `float[]`? Should I use `float *bar = myArray` instead? Not as readable but it works.

Comment: I do know the size of the arrays at compile time so your second option would work, but both of your suggestions have helped a lot. Thank you.

Comment: BTW, I changed my answer a little bit ... it seems that there was a syntax error blocking you from one of your solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You have mixed C with Java.

Try to change your typedef to

```
typedef float *fooType;
```

Afterwards, however you will not be able to initialize a variable of type fooType like

```
fooType myArray = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
```

because `fooType` is a pointer now.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth oops. thanks. I just wanted the OP's code to work.

Comment: Thanks Roman, Oli. It does work as I wrote it though: I can initialise my arrays and use them directly. I need to be able to initialise in the declaration as in the question. The only bit I can't yet do is then declare other variables that point to them.

Comment: @TimKemp You won't be able to do it. As the other answer says in C you *cannot* assign something to an *array variable*, only to it's *elements*.

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio 2013 I found that you could use constructs such as in this example. This also seems to work with Visual Studio 2015.

Notice that the use of `malloc()` to create an array of `fooType` requires a dereferenced pointer of type `pfooType` rather than the type of `fooType` or `*pfooType` to compile. I changed the `typedef` from `float` to `double` and the `sizeof(*p2)` changed from 4 to 8 bytes as expected.

```
#include <malloc.h>

typedef float fooType[], *pfooType;

int xxmain2(void)
{
    fooType myArray = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };   // define the array with its elements
    pfooType p = myArray;   // get a pointer to the array.
    int i;
    int  nElements = sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(*p);  // determine number of elements in the array.

    pfooType p2 = malloc(sizeof(*p2) * 5);  // malloc() an array of 5 elements.

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) p2[i] = (float)i * 10.0;  // initialize my malloced array.
    myArray[0] = *p;       // dereference pointer
    myArray[1] = p[1];     // use array subscripting with pointer

    for (i = 0, p = myArray; i < nElements; i++) *p++ = 0;   // increment the pointer to traverse the array.

    free(p2);
    return 0;
}
```

I also found that I could not create a specified size of an array with something like `fooType myRay2[10];` (compilation error of "error C2087: 'myRay2' : missing subscript") or something similar. And `fooType myRay2;` gives a compilation error of "error C2133: 'myRay2': unknown size".

So the only way seems to be to use initialization to size the array or to use `malloc()` to create an array of a particular size which then requires `free()`.